Why is the reference crossed out when getting a reference when using a firebase database in Flutter?

this is the problem.
I want to use realtime database with firebase and this problem is preventing me.
I think I'm using the old technique.

From the documentation of reference:

@Deprecated('Deprecated in favor of calling ref().')
DatabaseReference reference()
Returns a DatabaseReference accessing the root of the database.

So, use ref() instead of reference.
This exact use-case is also covered in the documentation on getting a database reference.

Thanks  Frank ı tried your method  and solve them.
